# How to skip versioning using Paper Trail on a model using has_paper_trail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I have to update a table with missing data from an importation. And I don't want paper trail to version this update. How can I skip the versioning for this one time execution without removing has_paper_trail from my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
Model.paper_trail_off!
```

Comment: it's now: Model.paper_trail.disable

Answer (score 1):

In latest version, however, you can do it like

```
PaperTrail.request.disable_model(YourModel)
```

[Official Doc](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#per-class)